# create action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When i use scaffold in rails , controller creates various methods like

> new,create,show,index etc

but here i can't understand transition of new action to create action

eg. when i click on new Post it look up for new action,now it render _form,but when at time of submit how data entered to that particular table, **where the create action of controller called and how ?**

**My posts_controller** is as

```
def new
@post = Post.new
@post.user_id = current_user.id
@post.save
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @post }
end
end

# GET /posts/1/edit
def edit
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
authorize! :manage, @post
end

# POST /posts
# POST /posts.json
def create
@post = Post.new(params[:post])

respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
    format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default scaffolding on form ([read here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#Creating%20New%20Posts))

> When the user clicks the Create Post button on this form, the browser
>   will send information back to the create action of the controller
>   (Rails knows to call the create action because the form is sent with
>   an HTTP POST request; that’s one of the conventions that were
>   mentioned earlier):

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html  { redirect_to(@post,
                    :notice => 'Post was successfully created.') }
      format.json  { render :json => @post,
                    :status => :created, :location => @post }
    else
      format.html  { render :action => "new" }
      format.json  { render :json => @post.errors,
                    :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

If you want customize an action on new form scaffold, you should add `:url => {:action => "YourActionName"}` on your form.

Example :

```
#form
form_for @post, :url => {:action => "YourActionName"}

#controller
def YourActionName
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html  { redirect_to(@post,
                    :notice => 'Post was successfully created.') }
      format.json  { render :json => @post,
                    :status => :created, :location => @post }
    else
      format.html  { render :action => "new" }
      format.json  { render :json => @post.errors,
                    :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

#route
match '/posts/YourActionName`, 'controllers#YourActionName', :via => :post
```

Answer (score 1):

It's all about HTTP verbs and routes.

Your form will make a POST request to the `/posts` route. If you list your routes using `rake routes`, you'll see that all POST requests to that specific route are being directed to the `create` action in `PostsController`, or `posts#create` for short.

Answer (score 1):

When you point your browser to `/posts/new`, it renders the `new` action, which presents you with a form to fill out (defined in `app/views/posts/new.html.erb` and `app/views/posts/_form.html.erb`.  When you click the *Submit* button in your form, it posts your data to the `create` action, which actually creates the record in the database.

Looking at your PostsController code, you probably *don't* want to have the line

```
@post.save
```

in your `new` action, since that will save a blank record to the database - whether the user completes the form or not.  And, you'll probably want to move

```
@post.user_id = current_user.id
```

to your `create` action, since that is where you're actually saving the post to the database.

Comment: ok,that means create is method which will be auto called at submit button !!